# Why doesn't Pythons unittest.assertRaises() raise an error here?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Using Python 3.5, why does all tests below pass when run? Since, an `Exception` is not raised when `div` is called, how come that `assertRaises()` doesn't complain?

According to the documentation for `assertRaises()`: "or fails if no exception is raised".

Can someone help me out?

```
..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.002s




def div(self, x, y):
    if y == 0:
        raise Exception("Division by zero")
    return x / y

class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test1(self):
        with self.assertRaises(Exception) as cm:
            self.div(2, 1)

    def test2(self):
        self.assertRaises(Exception, div, 2, 1)
```

Comment: Don't throw and catch `Exception`, because it's far too easy to accidentally catch the wrong thing, like the `TypeError` that's being thrown here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you have called `div` with wrong signature and exceptions was raised prior calling `div` (actual body of  `div` wasn't executed, exception was raised prior execution).

To get **more clear** picture of what's going on try to raise [ZeroDivisionError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ZeroDivisionError) from `div` and replace `assertRaises(Exception, ...` to `assertRaises(ZeroDivisionError, ...` within your test cases.

Comment: Thank you, but when calling div outside, why do I get the error: "Exception was unhandled by user code"?

Comment: Sounds like that message is coming from a weird shell you're running things in. Either way, you're getting that message because _there was an exception that was not handled by your code_, just like the message says

Comment: Indeed, it was Visual Studio that caused the problems. Running fine from command-line Python.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An exception **is** raised when you call `self.div()` because you've defined the `div` method outside of the `MyTest` class.

That's why it's a good idea to also verify the exception message in your test:

```
with self.assertRaises(Exception) as exc:
    self.div(2, 1)
self.assertEqual("Division by zero", str(exc.exception))
```

Comment: When the div method is called the right way, I get the error: "Exception was unhandled by user code" (Division by zero)? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

`self.assertRaises(Exception, lambda: div(2, 0))`